# How to put a TPL Dataflow TranformBlock or ActionBlock in a separate file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, tpl-dataflow

I want to use the TPL Dataflow for my .NET Core application and followed [the example from the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline#the-complete-example)

Instead of having all the logic in one file I would like to separate each `TransformBlock` and `ActionBlock` (I don't need the other ones yet) into their own files. A small `TransformBlock` example converting integers to strings

```
class IntToStringTransformer : TransformBlock<int, string>
{
    public IntToStringTransformer() : base(number => number.ToString()) { }
}
```

and a small `ActionBlock` example writing strings to the console

```
class StringWriter : ActionBlock<string>
{
    public StringWriter() : base(Console.WriteLine) { }
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work because the block classes are sealed. Is there a way I can organize those blocks into their own files?

Comment: Why do that at all? There's no reason to inherit from an ActionBlock or TransformationBlock, just to specify the lambda. `the block classes are sealed` yes, because there's no reason at all to inherit from them. You don't need a separate file, simply a separate method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think OP simply wants to keep his class where the blocks are used tidy. More of a "code organization" issue, than anything else?

Comment: Nothing prohibits you from using composition rather than inheritance. You could also use a `partial` class if you just want to split things up for organizational purposes.

Comment: @Fildor that's a XY Problem then, which can't be solved by inheriting, or creating single-method files

Comment: @JeroenMostert not in this case. That's like asking for a separate file for each LINQ *Select expression*. Not query, single operation expression

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree 100%. Maybe we can come up with a reasonable solution that does not use inheritance?

Comment: @OlafSvenson dataflow blocks are essentially functional constructs that get composed together into pipelines, not classes to extend. All that's needed are the *functions* that should be passed to the lambdas. If you want to organize your code you can create libraries/modules of related methods in separate files (eg DB methods, file parsing methods, export methods). You can even use separate static classes to create those modules - most block lambdas are stateless after all. Each pipeline can go into its own file then, to make it easy to find the specific pipeline you want

Comment: Have you ever used SSIS Dataflow? If not, install the SSIS extension in Visual Studio and try them. You don't create a separate class for each block in a 20-step pipeline. You have libraries of configurable blocks on one side with which you create dataflow files by including the blocks, connecting them and configuring them

Comment: ok thanks guys, I think I understood. But when having this sample `class IntToStringTransformer
    {
        public string Transform(int number) => number.ToString();
    }` Is there a way I can use instead of this `TransformBlock<int, string> intToStringTransformBlock = new TransformBlock<int, string>(new IntToStringTransformer().Transform);` something like this so I don't have to create an instance by myself? `new TransformBlock(typeof(IntToStringTransformer))` while `IntToStringTransformer` just implements the action by an interface?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the thing is that each transform step is complex and I would like to create a separate class per step. E.g. `ObjectAToObjectBParser`

Comment: **Why**? I have complex operations too. One of by steps parses an [IATA DISH file](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/bspdish/), a COBOL-like format with 100s of different fields. The parser is a project in itself. The block? Just a single TransformBlock calling the parser and emitting the 10-20K records in that file to the next block. It's not even in the same project as the parser.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you just explained exactly what OP is looking for?

Comment: @Fildor I'm doing this for 7 years. The point is for the OP to understand how this works and get out of the object-oriented mindset. Working with SSIS since 2000 helped a *lot* though as I already knew what a dataflow looks like.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Panagiotis explained, I think you have to put aside the OOP Mindset a little.
What you have with DataFlow are Buildingblocks that you configure to execute what you need. I'll try to create a little example of what I mean by that:

```
// Interface and impl. are in separate files. Actually, they could 
// even be in a different project ...
public interface IMyComplicatedTransform
{
     Task<string> TransformFunction(int input);
}

public class MyComplicatedTransform : IMyComplicatedTransform
{
     public Task<string> IMyComplicatedTransform.TransformFunction(int input)
     {
         // Some complex logic
     }
}

class DataFlowUsingClass{

     private readonly IMyComplicatedTransform myTransformer;
     private readonly TransformBlock<int , string> myTransform;
     // ... some more blocks ...

     public DataFlowUsingClass()
     {
          myTransformer = new MyComplicatedTransform(); // maybe use ctor injection?
          CreatePipeline();
     }

     private void CreatePipeline()
     {
          // create blocks
          myTransform = new TransformBlock<int, string>(myTransformer.TransformFunction);
          // ... init some more blocks

          // TODO link blocks
     }
}
```

I think this is the closest to what you are looking for to do.

What you end up with is a set of interfaces and implementations which can be tested independently. The client basically boils down to "gluecode".

Edit: As @Panagiotis correctly states, the interfaces are even superfluent. You could do without.

Comment: hmm yeah .. that's the way I had for now ... but I think I'll have to stick with it then :)

Comment: You don't even need the interfaces. Dataflow is inherently functional.

Comment: ^^ That's correct. Maybe that's just my personal "workflow", because I like to use DI. But you could do without interfaces. You just need some `Func<Tinput,TOutput>`.

Comment: how would you do it without interfaces? I'm using DI too so should I register the services without an interface? like so? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079277/do-we-need-interfaces-for-dependency-injection

Comment: Using DI, I'd just have interfaces. But that's going towards "opinionated". All of the above could also be organized quite differently. The gist is: Use the blocks to organize the pipeline, use Funcs to define what the blocks do. Where these Funcs come from: up to you.

Comment: @OlafSvenson Definitely also consider Panagiotis' answer concerning Factories and Extension Methods. That's what I meant by "could be organized differently". Hard to give an example in the scope of a SO answer, but maybe worthwhile to play around with the ideas and see if that would work out for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Dataflow steps/blocks/goroutines are fundamentally functional in nature and best organized as modules of factory functions, not separate classes. A TPL DataFlow pipeline is quite similar to a pipeline of function calls in F#, or any other language. In fact, one could look at it as a PowerShell pipeline, except it's easier to write.

There's no need to create a class or implement an interface to add a new function to that pipeline, you just add it and redirect the output to the next function.

TPL Dataflow blocks provide the primitives to construct a pipeline already and only require a transformation function. That's why they are sealed, to prevent misuse.

The natural way to organize dataflows is similar to F# too - create libraries with the *functions* that perform each job, putting them in modules of related functions. Those functions are stateless, so they can easily go into a static library, just like extension methods.

For example, there could be one module for database related functions that perform bulk inserts or read data, another to handle exports to various file formats, separate classes to call external web services, another to parse specific message formats.

**A real Example**

For the last 7 years I'm working with several complex pipelines for an Online Travel Agency (OTA). One of them calls several GDSs (the intermediaries between OTAs and airlines) to retrieve transaction information - ticket issues, refunds, cancellations etc. Next step retrieves the ticket records, the detailed ticket informations. Finally, the records are inserted into the database.

GDSs are too big to bother with standards, so their "SOAP" web services aren't even SOAP-compliant, much less follow WS-* standards. So each GDS needs a separate class library to call the services and parse the outputs. No dataflows there yet, the project is already complex enough

Writing the data to the database is pretty much the same always, so there's a separate project with methods that take eg an `IEnumerable<T>` and write it to the database with `SqlBulkCopy`.

It's not enough to load new data though, things often go wrong so I need to be able to load already stored ticket information.

**Organisation**

To preserve sanity :

- Each pipeline gets its own file:

  - A Daily pipeline to load new data,
  - A Reload pipeline to load all stored data
  - A "Rerun" pipeline to use the existing data *and* ask again for any missing data.
- Static classes are used to hold the worker functions and *separately* factory methods that produce Dataflow blocks based on configuration. Eg, a `CreateLogger(path,level)` creates an `ActionBlock<Message>` that logs specific messages.
- Common *dataflow* extension methods - since DataFlow blocks follow the same basic patterns, it's easy to create a logged block by combining eg a `Func<TIn,TOut>` and a logger block. Or create a `LinkTo` overload that redirects bad records to a logger or database. Those are common enough they can become extension methods.

If those were in the same file, it would be very hard to edit one pipeline without affecting another. Besides, there's a lot more to a pipeline than the core tasks, eg:

- Logging
- Handling bad records and partial results (can't stop a 100K import for 10 errors)
- error handling (which isn't the same as handling bad records)
- *monitoring* - what's this monster doing for the last 15 minutes? Did a DOP=10 improve performance at all?

*Don't create a parent pipeline class*.

Some of the steps are common, so at first, I created a parent class with common steps that got overloaded, or simply replaced in child classes. *VERY BAD IDEA*. Each pipeline is similar but not quite, and inheritance means that modifying one step or one connection risks breaking everything. After about 1 year things became unbearable, so I split the parent class into separate classes.

Comment: Very interesting to read some "field experience"! Thank you for that.

Comment: @Fildor I made extensive edits, as I hit `Enter` by mistake earlier on

Comment: All that really sounds **awesome**. I instantly feel the urge to create some "dummy example" project to share on github since I feel this would be a bit too much for a SO answer ...

Comment: I just spent the weekend learning all about and implementing a dataflow pipeline... and every time I found a helpful answer on SO and scrolled down to see who wrote it, it was @PanagiotisKanavos